# How can I submit 5 items from the same checkbox list form into 5 differents column in a db?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, checkbox

I have a big list of elements (tools), and I want a user to select a maximum of 5 of them and send them into 5 differents columns in a database...

I'm using Razor
This is a part of the @code I believe is ok

```
@{
var db = Database.Open("Tool");
    var insertCommand = "INSERT INTO DTool (NoEmpl, Nom, Outil1, Outil2, Outil3, Outil4, Outil5, Auto, Date) VALUES(@0, @1, @2, @3, @4, @5, @6, @7, @8)";
    db.Execute(insertCommand, NoEmpl, Nom, Outil1, Outil2, Outil3, Outil4, Outil5, Auto, Date);
}
```

Here is an exemple of the list:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="Outil" value="Brocheuse #T25 - 38385">Brocheuse #T25 - 38385<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="Outil" value="Clé 7/16 x 1/2 - 10196">Clé 7/16" x 1/2" - 10196<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="Outil" value="Couteau à lame fixe - 10311">Clé 7/16" x 1/2" - 10311<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="Outil" value="Lampe à casque jaune Head light - 10529">Lampe à casque jaune Head light - 10529<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="Outil" value="Outil antivol (GTP) TPLOCK - 10573">Outil antivol (GTP) TPLOCK - 10573<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="Outil" value="Outil SST 59 (Douille MTA) - 10572">Outil SST 59 (Douille MTA) - 10572<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="Outil" value="Pince 2 positions - 10616">Pince 2 positions - 10616<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="Outil" value="Pince ajustable multipositions - 10608">Pince ajustable multipositions - 10608<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="Outil" value="Pince coupante 7'' - 10613">Pince coupante 7'' - 10613<br>
```

I need to be able to select a maximum of 5 items from the list and send them into 5 differents columns (outil1, outil2, outil3, outil4 and outil5) of a db (same line)

I know now how to group the checkboxes... If I put the name Outil1 to all checkboxes name one of the selected item work and go into the colum outil1 in the db. Unfortunatly, I don't know how to make the four other go into the db...

Can anyone help me a bit?
p.s. Sorry for my english

Answer (score 0):

You should use a controller for doing the database work, and put your checkboxes inside a @Html.BeginForm(), calling the controller method which can accept a string-array as parameter, which would have the name Outil.

See something similar here: http://www.appsdiaries.com/Article/3

Comment: Arf I think it's too hard for me... I'll create 5 différents radio button list and try to make it look ok...